# Hosting Options for Django, PostgreSQL and Java Cron Job support

Tags: java, scheduling, hosted, django

Can you please provide your advice on Web Hosting options for the below.

1) Django Web application with PostgreSQL as backend. 
+ 
2) Java Cron job that writes to PosgreSQL (Scheduled to run twice daily)

I looked at GAE (expensive), Go Daddy (Java Support not available), Heroku (Still considering).

I understand that Django and Java are diverse technologies. I was comfortable with Java for building some complicated logic and Django for the quick web framework. So I ended up with the above diverse technologies in my app.

I am looking for any viable alternatives to host the above.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

*Moved this thread from StackOverflow as I came across this forum specific to Recommendations

Comment: Sorry, but hosting recommendations are off-topic here at Software Recommendations

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just use Digital Ocean. You can do whatever you want on there.

Comment: This answer as it stands is very low quality, please in the future expand on your answers specifically addressing the requirements in the question.